# Creating Modules and using them

Tags: python

I am playing around with creating modules.I have two python scripts.The first (the module) has:

```
def abspath(relpath):

    import os
    absdir = os.path.realpath('__file__')
    absdir = absdir.split('_')[0].replace('\\', '/') 
    filename = str(absdir + relpath )
    print (filename)

    return filename;
```

The second file (main) has:

```
import file_tools as ft

filename = ft.abspath('some/path/')
```

When I run Main, filename appears empty (Type:None). I have run the `filename = abspath(etc)` within the 'module', and it works. Clearly, I am missing something here!!

and doing this, so any help would be useful.

Thank's all.

MT

Comment: Please go back to that StackOverflow answer where you copied `os.path.realpath('__file__')` from and give it a downvote. That's the most complicated way of getting the current working directory I've ever seen. Your `abspath` function _would_ be functionally equivalent to `os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(relpath))` if it wasn't riddled with bugs.

Comment: To address your actual question, make sure you're importing the correct module. You can find out if it's importing the correct file by running `import file_tools; print(file_tools.__file__)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem lies in how you're finding the working directory; the preferred method being [`os.getcwd()`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/os.html#os.getcwd) (or [`os.getcwdb`](https://docs.python.org/3.0/library/os.html#os.getcwdb) for Unix compatibility). Using that, we can see that your function boils down to:

```
def abspath(relpath):
    return os.path.join(os.getcwd(), relpath)
```